# CSRF prevention using local storage and cookie

Tags: security, csrf

The following talk https://youtu.be/67mezK3NzpU?t=2408 at 40:08min, Hubert mentions that the best way to prevent a CSRF attack is to do the following:

1. Generate a random id server side - lets call this the CSRF id.
2. Add this id to your jwt cookie. Also add a response header with the id (e.g. csrfId: xxx)
3. Have the client save the id to local storage.
4. On each request, the client should append a header with this id.
5. On each request, the server should verify that the id in the received cookie matches the one in the received header.

My question is: what would stop the CSRF attacker reading the cookie manually, getting the ID and then adding that to the attack request?

Also, wont localstorage leave the ID vulnerable to a XSS + CSRF combination attack? (I'm not sure this is possible)?

Answer (score 2):

> what would stop the CSRF attacker reading the cookie manually, getting the ID and then adding that to the attack request?

Setting the [cookie attribute HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) makes it inaccessible to Javascript. [Using a custom request header](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers) prevents an attacker from adding the ID to the attack request:

> «This defense relies on the same-origin policy (SOP) restriction that only JavaScript can be used to add a custom header, and only within its origin. By default, browsers do not allow JavaScript to make cross origin requests with custom headers.» -https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers

> Also, wont localstorage leave the ID vulnerable to a XSS + CSRF combination attack? (I'm not sure this is possible)?

CSRF protection can be [bypassed if you have a XSS vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf), regardless of using localstorage.
However, [OWASP explicitly recommends *not* storing the CSRF token in cookies or local storage](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#storing-the-csrf-token-value-in-the-dom).

So I think your question is warranted, and I don't understand how that can be the best way to prevent a CSRF attack.

If I may, I recommend you check out the [OWASP CSRF prevention cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) if you haven't seen it already.